# Android - is it possible to interact with apps?

Tags: android, mobile

I wanted to know if an app can interact with and change behavior of other apps ? Like, if someone has my app installed and opens whatsapp, I would pre-fill the input with a default text, for example.

It doesn't matter if the phone needs to be rooted. I didn't find any way to do this so just wanted your input !

Thanks !

Comment: This is what ContentProvider does. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Indeed, ContentProvider is thought to be a "sand-box" area between applications.  For example: [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm)

Comment: Thanks guys ! How did I missed that ? And I don't need anything from the other app provider (to follow the example above, whatsapp) in order to do that type of things ?

Comment: The other app needs to be using a ContentProvider (I don't know if WhatsApp has one). Other apps can interact with the ContentProvider app by using ContentResolver. This only works for apps that open up their content in this way. Otherwise, your app can't access the other app without employing other more hacky means (like taking over keyboard/input method, etc.).

Comment: If you want to post as an answer I will validate it so you get your points

Comment: Haha, yes, gimme point! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other app needs to be using a `ContentProvider` (I don't know if WhatsApp has one). See the [reference doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). Other apps can interact with the `ContentProvider` app by using `ContentResolver`. This only works for apps that open up their content in this way. Otherwise, your app can't access the other app without employing other more hacky means (like taking over keyboard/input method, etc.).